# Keras One hot encoding (to_categorical) returns wrong output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an output with three distinctive classes:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(y_train)
```

> array([0, 2, 5], dtype=uint8)

When I one-hot-encode it using the following code, I get an output with the shape of (number of instances, 6), not (number of instances, 3).

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
y_train.shape
```

> (17302, 6)

I also passed the number of classes (3) to `to_categorical` function, but it complained:

> IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

Does anybody have any ideas about this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is because the `to_categorical` function assumes that the input labels start from 0 and are consecutive integers up to the number of classes minus 1.In your case, you have classes 0, 2, and 5, which are not consecutive, and this is causing the error.

In order to solve it, one way is to map the output classes. Take a look at this code as an example :

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Assuming y_train and y_test are your original labels
# Map the original labels to consecutive integers
class_mapping = {0: 0, 2: 1, 5: 2}

y_train_mapped = np.array([class_mapping[label] for label in y_train])
y_test_mapped = np.array([class_mapping[label] for label in y_test])

# Now, apply one-hot encoding with the correct number of classes
num_classes = len(class_mapping)
y_train_encoded = to_categorical(y_train_mapped, num_classes=num_classes)
y_test_encoded = to_categorical(y_test_mapped, num_classes=num_classes)

# Check the shape
print(y_train_encoded.shape)
print(y_test_encoded.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this problem using Scikit Learn that I tried in advance and worked for me with no problem:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    
enc = OneHotEncoder()    
y_train = enc.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
y_test = enc.fit_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

> (17302, 3)

> (2904, 3)